# USB-connection from android to phone

Tags: java, android, usb

I'm trying to send data from android to a computer via USB,
I found the USB Accessory  introduction, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html (Basically I want to send a few bytes to a programm on the computer) So, am i right on using the accessory on android? What would i use for the pc programm, and can I/ Do i have to create a socket connection from my application to the programm

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to the USB device plugged in to the PC which lets you send USB Control Request and Bulk Transfer requests.

If you are using linux, you could try libusb - which is pretty straight forward to use. For windows am not sure though.